# PL/SQL error : 00947 No hay suficientes valores

Tags: plsql, oracle-11g

Tengo un query donde extraigo unos registros , quiero hacer facil la modificacion del día de consulta(la tengo que modificar manualmente en todos las lineas), hasta ahora debo colocar manualmente la fecha en cada condicion  (sysdate - aqui va un numero),  mi intencion es declarar la variable una sola vez , este es mi código planteado pero me a error

```
DECLARE dia := 2;
SELECT
    COUNT(ctd.id_cuenta),
    ctd.cod_status_cuenta,
    ctd.cod_marca,
    xtecnologia,
    num_dias_inactividad,
    trunc((sysdate - dia)- cta.fecha_fin) dias_morosidad,
    mer.desc_mercado,
    CASE
        WHEN num_dias_inactividad >=0 and num_dias_inactividad <=10 
        THEN '0 - 10'
        ELSE '90+'
        END AS RANGO_INACTIVIDAD,
    CASE
        WHEN trunc((sysdate - dia)- cta.fecha_fin) >=0 and  trunc((sysdate - dia)- cta.fecha_fin) <=10 THEN '0 - 10'
        WHEN trunc((sysdate - dia)- cta.fecha_fin) >=11 and trunc((sysdate - dia)- cta.fecha_fin) <=15 THEN '11 - 15'
        ELSE '80+'
        END AS RANGO_MOROSIDAD
INTO (dia)
FROM 
    Db.tabla subpartition(tbl_cta_p3_dia1) ctd, 
    Db2.tabla2 subpartition(tbl_inac_p3_dia1) inac, 
    Db3.ta
LEFT join 
    Db.tabl4 mer on cod_mercado = cod_mercado
--WHERE ctd.cod_marca IN ('I','RTM','A','AI','RT','RTI','RTD','RTDI','AG','AGI','AGF','AGFI','BC1','BC2','BC3','BC4','BC5')
WHERE ctd.cod_marca IN ('BT', 'BTI', 'BRM', 'BRMI', 'BTM')
AND cod_tipo_producto = 'BSI0101'
AND cod_tipo_clase <> 'OFC'
AND id_plataforma = '2'
AND id_cuenta =  inac.id_cuenta and ctd.id_cuenta = cta.id_cuenta
GROUP BY 
    ctd.cod_status_cuenta,
    ctd.cod_marca,
    xtecnologia,
    num_dias_inactividad, 
    trunc((sysdate -dia )- cta.fecha_fin),
    mer.desc_mercado;
END;
```

EL error dice que:

> ORA-00947:no hay suficientes valores

Pero no entiendo que quiere decir.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tal y como lo escribió NO es una consulta sino un bloque anónimo, le falta BEGIN, le falta definir 9 variables que requiere la claúsula INTO para recibir las 9 columnas del SELECT, la variable "dia" le hace falta el tipo de dato.

Comment: Pues no sabemos cómo estás definiendo `dia` pero se ve problemático que lo inicialices en `2` y luego le asignes las nueve columnas resultantes de ejecutar la consulta.